# Java Script required to Change on Text input

Tags: oninput

I have got a Text box in which, if an input come that Contains "DO NOT PEND".
This can be @ the Start or End.
There is a Label that get Triggered that Should say "Contact Tier 3".

Contact Tier 3

Not sure what can be used.

Comment: Make a custom script that is called for the `oninput` event.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript to attach an event listener to listen for the `input` event, then use the `includes()` method to check whether the substring is contained in the input. The method will return true if the substring is found, or false if not.

For example:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (event.target.value.includes('DO NOT PEND')) {
    // trigger your label here
  }
})
```